# Hartl's railstutorial listing 8.4 rspec tests failing strangely

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm working through Michael Hartl's railstutorial book and I've come to a strange behavior that I can't seem to troubleshoot. In the listing 8.4 it says the rspec tasks should be passing, however I'm getting a failure, with the error being:

```
Failures:

  1) Authentication signin page 
     Failure/Error: before { visit signin_path }
     AbstractController::ActionNotFound:
       The action 'sign_in' could not be found for StaticPagesController
     # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:8:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) Authentication signin page 
     Failure/Error: before { visit signin_path }
     AbstractController::ActionNotFound:
       The action 'sign_in' could not be found for StaticPagesController
     # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:8:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.11364 seconds
2 examples, 2 failures
```

I don't understand why it's looking for 'sign_in' path instead of 'signin' which I have in my routes:

```
  match '/signup',  to: 'users#new',             via: 'get'
  match '/signin',  to: 'sessions#new',          via: 'get'
  match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy',      via: 'delete'
```

The rspec test also doesn't ask for 'sing_in'... it uses 'signin_path' in the test:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Authentication" do

  subject { page }

  describe "signin page" do
    before { visit signin_path }

    it { should have_content('Sign in') }
    it { should have_title('Sign in') }
  end
end
```

Is rails or rspec automatically transcribing signin to sign_in? And also why is it looking for it in the StaticPagesController instead of the SessionsController? - I guess this is because it's looking for /sign_in instead of /signin? So it sounds like rspec is changing it to sign_in?

Answer (score 0):

well, I think I figured out the issue. In Michael's routes.rb file, he has:

```
root 'static_pages#home'
```

However, when I changed it to:

```
root to: 'static_pages#home'
```

All the tests pass now. It makes sense that root was defining the static_pages controller as the default controller to look for paths. by adding 'to:' it just matches the '/' path to static_pages#home. Maybe I'm wrong, but that's what it looks like to me so far.